# Parsing a SQL Query Report with Bizarrely Formatted Entries

Tags: c#, sql-server, string-parsing

I am currently writing a C# program that parses a SQL Server query report for data that it then saves for later use. So far, the queries I've been parsing have been very straightforward, but I just received a test file that contains this entry:

```
Client Contact                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Client Email
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary: Nelli Quiroga

, nelli.quiroga@parservicios.com 
Secondary: Zully Aranda, zully.aranda@parservicios.com
                                                                                                                                                nelli.quiroga@parservicios.com|zully.aranda@parservicios.com
```

(Please excuse the formatting - that's exactly how the query outputs it.)

I need to be able to pull the names and email addresses of both the Primary and Secondary clients, which will then be stored in a `List<Tuple<string, string>>`. So far, I haven't been able to devise a solution that does it efficiently, if at all. My best guess is that I would have to use Regex somehow, but I'm not familiar with how Regex works in C#, and my regex skills are very rusty.

Some additional information:

- I do not have access to the database, so I can't change the formatting.
- I do not know whether or not the query result can/will contain more than one such entry. Because of this, I would like for the parser to handle more than one of these entries if present.
- This entry(ies) will be part of a query report that contains other table queries, which thankfully are all formatted like so:

  ```
  User_Name                                          Group_Name
  -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
  msteffl                                            NULL
  spurcell                                           Admin
  wgervais                                           Admin
  djames                                             Admin
  loaduser                                           Admin
  mbreu                                              Admin
  wgervais                                           ComplianceContractors
  wgervais                                           ComplianceOfficers
  sgregory                                           ComplianceOfficers
  ntabares                                           ComplianceOfficers
  lduffaut                                           ComplianceOfficers
  pdeneree                                           ComplianceOfficers
  serickson                                          ComplianceOfficers
  mbreu                                              ComplianceOfficers
  jreinhardt                                         ComplianceOfficers
  jromoser                                           ComplianceOfficers
  ebell                                              ComplianceOfficers
  bkeogh                                             ComplianceOfficers
  cbarnett                                           ComplianceOfficers
  cbarnett                                           Users
  bkeogh                                             Users
  ebell                                              Users
  djames                                             Users
  jromoser                                           Users
  jreinhardt                                         Users
  mbreu                                              Users
  serickson                                          Users
  pdeneree                                           Users
  lduffaut                                           Users
  ntabares                                           Users
  sgregory                                           Users
  spurcell                                           Users
  wgervais                                           Users
  ```

Any and all input would be appreciated.

Comment: That looks like the kind of "report" you get when you check "output to file" in Management Studio, or invoke `sqlcmd`. You don't have to modify any queries to get better formatted output if that's the case, just a better way to process the output. You say you have "no access", but it's still worthwhile to go back to the source and ask if they could, you know, at least try to copy-paste the grid result in Management Studio and paste that in Excel, which requires little extra technical sophistication.

Comment: To stress: this format is *not* designed to allow consistent parsing by machines. Any parsing you devise can probably be broken by creative application of newlines in the data, which the format makes no attempt to escape. If this *is* output from Management Studio, be aware that it will also truncate data if there's enough of it. Effectively it becomes impossible to separate columns from rows, except by the kind of guessing that will make your processing unreliable enough as to be worthless.

Comment: Yes, this is an output file. The biggest issue with asking them to paste the data into another file I can think of is that I don't know if that would be desirable. The extra step of copy-pasting the query result to a spreadsheet might be considered too tedious and inefficient, but regardless I can still ask them. If possible, though, I (and they) would appreciate figuring this out as well.

Comment: If you fail to convince the fine folks that gave you that file, you could still try to experiment with Regexes. This one seems to work with that specific sample data: `(?:Primary:\s+)(?<primaryName>[^,]*),(?<primaryEmail>.+)|(?:Secondary:\s+)(?<secondaryName>[^,]*),(?<secondaryEmail>.+)`

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Avo. I was also able to generate a RegEx that seems to work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after some trial and error, I was able to write a regular expression that works just fine with the contact output I was given. I cannot guarantee that it will work well with *any* output file I can/will be given, but for now it does what I need it to do.

This is the regular expression in question:

`(?:Primary|Secondary):[ ]*[\r\n]*[a-zA-Z ]+[\r\n]*[ ]*,[ ]*[\r\n]*[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]+[ ]*[\r\n]*`

It is able to break up the entry into two parts, the Primary and Secondary contact, which then allows me to trim and split each contact as needed.

Again, I cannot say for certain that this will work with any given input, but I also think I've managed to make it reasonably foolproof, hence all the instances of `[ ]*` and `[\r\n]*`.